# Questions tagged with "Vaadin" should interpret code snippets as Java

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, language-hints

On this post
[Use GridLayout to make a smart layout that responds to the window being resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891119/use-gridlayout-to-make-a-smart-layout-that-responds-to-the-window-being-resized)
someone had to add the hidden language specifiers to flag the code snippets as Java.

However:

1. Vaadin code is always Java code (almost always*).
2. I've read that StackOverflow.com has a goal of having the language of code snippets be automatically detected.

Can someone add a language-hint to the [vaadin](/questions/tagged/vaadin) tag pointing to Java?

---

(*) 'Almost always' means rarely the code snippet might be CSS or even less likely JavaScript. Those are exceptions, as the main point of Vaadin is to write apps in pure Java without knowing CSS, JavaScript, DOM, etc.

Comment: This is the right place to ask; moderators can add the hint to tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does that mean my work here is done? Need I take any more steps?

Comment: Your work is done; you requested the change in the correct place; people may express opinions about the request (including voting; voting on Meta signifies approval or disapproval of a proposal), and give feedback to which you could respond.

Answer (score 2):

I set the syntax highlighting to "default" which basically means that it will be inferred from the code.

Let me know if that's not enough and [vaadin](/questions/tagged/vaadin) should have a more explicit syntax highlighting setting.